# [Node.js] MySQL query в nodejs

Tags: node.js, mysql, javascript

Добрый день, в node.js совсем недавно, столкнулся с задачей, нужно получить таблицы из базы,
установил db-mysql, добавил в app.js

```
var mysql = require('db-mysql');
new mysql.Database({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'dd_axo'
}).on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
}).connect();
module.exports.mysql = mysql;
```

Далее пытаюсь вызвать query скриптом из html в layout.jade

```
      mysql.query().select('*').from('livemsg').execute(function(error, result) {
      result = result.id;
      });
```

на что получаю ошибку mysql is not defined 
Подскажите где и как его задефайнить надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос не должен быть в шаблоне, в шаблон передаются уже полученные из БД данные. Запрос базе должен быть внутри действия, например:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  mysql.query('SELECT * FROM livemsg', function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.render('index', {
      title: results[0].title,
      results: results
    });
  }
});
```

и отображаем это через Jade:

```
- for( var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++ ) {
  .result
    .field1= results[i].field1
    .field2= results[i].field2
- }
```